# jQuery :odd and :nth-child CSS3 different

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I found that jQuery :odd selector and CSS3 nth-child(odd) works different.
http://jsfiddle.net/TMDwT/5/

In yellow it's CSS nth-child(odd) and if you uncomment JS and comment background: yellow in CSS you will find that it found in another way.

Can anybody say how I achieve the same result as in jQuery but with CSS3?

Thanks!

Comment: your nested list is incorrectly formatted. `li` elements need to be children of `menu`, `ol`, or `ul` elements.

Comment: Pardon, fixed. But issue still exist. http://jsfiddle.net/TMDwT/5/

Comment: How about using nth-child(odd) in jQuery?

Comment: @Hexxagonal: jQuery's `:nth-child()` is a carbon copy of the CSS3 counterpart, so there will be no difference.

Comment: @BoltClock That's my point... he's wondering how to do the same result in jQuery and CSS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [:odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) and [:nth-child(odd)](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) are not the same thing:

- `:odd` matches the odd items *within the matched elements*, i.e. the contents of the jQuery object you apply the selector to,
- `:nth-child(odd)` matches the odd items *within their respective parents*.

This is the same difference as between `:first` and `:first-child`, or `:last` and `:last-child`.

*Update:* As zzzzBov and BoltClock rightfully point out, the `:odd` selector is zero-based but the `:nth-child()` selector is one-based. This means that even if you apply the two selectors to the complete child list of an element (thus removing the difference between `:odd` and `:nth-child(odd)`), they still won't match the same elements.

Comment: And the answer to "Can I do this in CSS3?" is no.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that `:odd` uses 0-based indices while `:nth-child` uses 1-based indices. Which means that across a single list they would still not represent the same selection.

Comment: @zzzzBov, absolutely, but the questioner explicitly refers to `:nth-child(odd)`, so it being one-based is not really a concern in this particular case :)

Comment: @Alex, CSS selectors do not have a concept of *the currently matched elements*, so `:odd` does not have a equivalent there.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Actually, it does matter. The difference in their indices is precisely why the odd and even keywords behave differently.

Comment: @BoltClock, ah, I did not read that from the right angle at first. `:odd` and `:nth-child(odd)` will indeed match alternate elements if applied on all the children of an element. I'll try to clarify that in my answer.