# color text in divs with two colors using css only - tricky

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

OK, let me rewrite my question in another words so it looks clear and interesting: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xY6T3/1/)

I need a pure css solution that colorizes the lines of text in the color depending whether the line is odd or even.

The example of code could be :

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="zipcode12345">
        <div class="myclass">red with css</div>
        <div class="myclass">blue with css</div>
        <div class="myclass">red with css</div>
        <div class="myclass">blue with css</div>
        <div class="myclass">red with css</div>
    </div>
    <div class="zipcode23456">
        <div class="myclass">blue with css</div>
    </div>
    <div class="zipcode90033">
        <div class="myclass">red with css</div>
        <div class="myclass">blue with css</div>
        <div class="myclass">red with css</div>
    </div>
    <div class="zipcode11321">
        <div class="myclass">blue with css</div>
        <div class="myclass">red with css</div>
        <div class="myclass">blue with css</div>
        <div class="myclass">red with css</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make it with css? As you see [@ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xY6T3/1/), it is not colorized as expected.

So, the main div is "main".
The inner `div`s always have class names in format "zipcodeXXXXX", as you see.
The number of zipcodeXXXXX is variable, the number of `myclass` is variable.
However, the odd lines should be always red and the even lines should be always blue.
Does pure css solution exist?

That would be kind of

```
.myclass:nth-child(2n+1){
 color:red;
}
.myclass:nth-child(2n){
 color:blue;
}
```

if we could igonre `"zipcodeXXXXX"` divs, right?

Thank you.

Comment: The jsFiddle was updated to http://jsfiddle.net/xY6T3/1/ so it is more clear. Thank you.

Comment: No, that is not possible with the markup structure that you currently have – the `nth-child` selector always looks at an element within the bounds of its parent element. (The hint is in the _name_ …)

Comment: That's what I think after spending several hours before I decided to ask the question here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply apply different odd/even rules to the parent elements as well as the child elements:

```css
div[class^="zipcode"]:nth-of-type(odd) .myclass:nth-of-type(odd),
div[class^="zipcode"]:nth-of-type(even) .myclass:nth-of-type(even) {
    color: red;
}

div[class^="zipcode"]:nth-of-type(odd) .myclass:nth-of-type(even),
div[class^="zipcode"]:nth-of-type(even) .myclass:nth-of-type(odd) {
    color: blue;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xY6T3/9/).

Comment: I cannot edit html in my case. zipced is what I can't change or modify. That's why I'm looking for a css solution. Does it exist? Thank you.

Comment: Please update your JSFiddle link, it links to my question, not your solution:) However, seems like you found a solution. Let me doublecheck it several more times:)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, your new approach just switches the coloring of odd and even based on whether the `.zipcode` is an odd or even child – but that will still not give the desired result if the number of `.myclass` elements is not the “right” one.

Comment: Is CBroe right? Please see here http://jsfiddle.net/xY6T3/10/ the 6th and 7th strings are blue.

Comment: Seems like if the number of string is even, it breaks the order right after it.

Comment: @Haradzieniec there's not really much you can do about that unless you introduce some JavaScript to iterate through each `.myclass` element.

Comment: People voted +3 for the wrong answer that I hoped it is correct, but no one upvoted for the question :) 
James Donnelly, thank you anyway for your answer. Anyway it looks tricky although my question has probably no solution with pure css (yet, as of 2014).

Answer (score 1):

```
.zipcode12345:nth-child(odd) { background-color: red; }
.zipcode12345:nth-child(even) { background-color: blue; }

.zipcode23456:nth-child(odd){ background-color: blue; }

.zipcode90033:nth-child(odd){ background-color: red; }
.zipcode90033:nth-child(even){ background-color: blue; }

.zipcode11321:nth-child(odd){ background-color: blue; }
.zipcode11321:nth-child(even){ background-color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
.myclass:nth-of-type(odd) {
    color: red;
}

.myclass:nth-of-type(even) {
    color: blue;
}
```

I've just used the code that @James Donnelly provided.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just for people who wants to find a solution.

This is NOT a solution (guess why? - the same thing as with css solution above):

```
jQuery(".main .myclass:nth-child(odd)").css('color', 'blue');
```

And this is a solution:

```
jQuery(".main .myclass:odd").css('color', 'blue');
```

The difference explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044910/jquery-odd-and-nth-child-css3-different) by Frédéric Hamidi.